# Excel formula How to get data count from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On **`C123`** **`=COUNTIFS(Data!A:A,A123,Data!E:E,Data!G:G,B123,Data!Q:Q,"mobilepod")`**

its giving me Error, I know I'm missing criteria2 but isn't that an optional?

I have also tried 
**`=COUNTIFS(Data!A:A,A123,Data!E:E,"",Data!G:G,B123,Data!Q:Q,"mobilepod")`**

No Errors no result

[image]

Data Sheet

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the data in the Data sheet it is hard to say why you get 0 hits. I used your formula with rows meeting the criterias, and then it does return the correct number of rows matching the criterias.

Just to check, you do want to count rows that match ALL these criterias right? I.e. you do not want to count rows that meet ANY (but not all) criterias?

Comment: @johankr  Yes - data sheet posted

Comment: PAIRS of criteria_ranges and criteria beyond the first pair are optional, yes. But you cannot have a criteria_range without a criteria! Why is Data!E:E in your formula all on its own? There is no criteria associated with this range, so why is it there?

Comment: Data!E3582 is **DIST**, not blank or a zero-length string.

Comment: @Jeeped I need to count both **DIST & DIST 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an **OR** logic in one of the criteria for your [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED), put the multiple ctrieria values in as an array of constants and wrap the whole thing in a [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57).

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(data!A:A, A123, data!E:E, {"DIST","DIST 2"}, data!G:G, B123, data!Q:Q, "mobilepod"))
```